# Scope of variable within "with" statement?

Tags: python, scope, with-statement

I am reading only the first line in Python using:

```py
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    my_count = f.readline()
print(my_count)
```

I am a little confused about the scope of the `my_count` variable. Although the print statement works fine, wouldn't it be better to do something like `my_count = 0` outside the `with` statement first (e.g., in C I would do `int my_count = 0`)?

Comment: I see no `logs_count` in the provided code. Did you mean `my_count`?

Comment: that code is fine, no need to initialize `my_count` outside the loop in python

Answer (score 146, accepted):

A `with` statement does **not create a scope** (like `if`, `for` and `while` do not create a scope either).

As a result, Python will analyze the code and see that you made an assignment in the `with` statement, and thus that will make the variable local (to the real scope).

In Python variables do not need *initialization* in *all code paths*: as a programmer, you are responsible to make sure that a variable is assigned before it is used. This can result in shorter code: say for instance you know for sure that a list contains at least one element, then you can assign in a `for` loop. In Java assignment in a `for` loop is not considered safe (since it is possible that the body of the loop is never executed).

Initialization *before* the `with` scope can be safer in the sense that after the `with` statement we can safely assume that the variable exists. If on the other hand the variable *should* be assigned in the `with` statement, not initializing it before the `with` statement actually results in an additional check: Python will error if somehow the assignment was skipped in the `with` statement.

A with statement is only used for context management purposes. It forces (by syntax) that the context you open in the `with` is closed at the end of the indentation.

Comment: So Do I need initialization ? Or I can use variable my_count outside the with  statement like I am doing. What would be better practice ?

Comment: @crystal: I updated the answer with more information about that. Does this answers your question?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :D

Comment: It feels really un-Pythonic though. I try to avoid using variables initialized in a for loop later, and variables I assign in an if-block always have a similar assignment in an else-block. Similar with try/except blocks. While such a safe-guard would not be necessary for with-statements, it just looks /wrong/ somehow. Assignments in if-statements also feel a little bad, so I prefer conditional expressions. Unfortunately with-statements don't seem to have something similar..

Comment: @BlackShift: yes but for `with` statements, it is another case. Since the body is executed (until an exception or the end). It is sometimes good to make a `with` statement as short as possible, since it for instance opens a file, and we want to close the file as soon as possible.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem, Yeah, I really have to train myself to make my with-blocks short. What usually happens is that I 1) write a function with a with-statement (mostly opening a file), 2) automatically put everything that (indirectly) uses the 'as' variable in the block, including any return-statement, 3) realize that return statements should (normally) not be in a block, 4) unindent almost everything again (usually only except 'read'), 5) feel bad because the code doesn't look nice to my eyes :-). But well.

Answer (score 8):

You should also go through PEP-343 and [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#with). It will clear that its not about creating scope its about using [Context Manager](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers). I am quoting python documentation on context manager

> A context manager is an object that defines the runtime context to be established when executing a with statement. The context manager handles the entry into, and the exit from, the desired runtime context for the execution of the block of code. Context managers are normally invoked using the with statement (described in section The with statement), but can also be used by directly invoking their methods.
>
> Typical uses of context managers include saving and restoring various kinds of global state, locking and unlocking resources, closing opened files, etc.