# What happens when a resource-managed variable is used outside of its scope?

Tags: python, resource-management

I am working with the following snippet of tensorflow related code:

```py
def train_step(emb, y_onehot, step):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      logits = model(emb, training=True)
      assert model.trainable_variables
      logits.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(y_onehot.shape)
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_true=y_onehot, y_pred=logits)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables) # tape!
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
```

The line marked `tape!` is used outside/after the `with` resource management scope. I had actually thought this would have been a syntax error. So does it become a normal variable at that point?  Are there other implications of this usage?

Comment: I expect that you'll get a runtime error. The variable is still in scope, but the object associated with it will have been closed (or whatever context the `with` is handling).

Comment: It will very much depend on that `tf.GradientTape()` does here. A file pointer can still exists outside the with-block, but you can't actually access the file's contents anymore. Here, I don't know, but given that `tape` is only used outside the with-block, this seems like rather awkward code in the first place.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45100308/4588779

Comment: @Ankush Nice find; that's probably the duplicate of this question.